# Ajax/PHP issues on IE8

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer

While working on a web application for a client I have stumbled on a bit of a paradox.
The application is PHP/Ajax and we've tested it on all major browsers, including IE7-IE8.

However a client who has windows7 and I believe has IE8 is getting the error message below, and the application hangs, but when I use it on IE, Firefox and Chrome its fine.

Could this be down to a security issue on the browser that we could change the setting on as Their IE8 and my IE8 aren't matching up.

[image]

Comment: As usual, IE's error messages are entirely unhelpful. We'll need to see the code before we can give any real help here.

Comment: IE8's error messages are actually quite useful since the line numbers are usually correct (it's not like IE6 days when the line numbers were meaningless)...  So look at line 112 of the file posted, and see what it's trying to do...

Comment: I often find that most of IE's errors come from arrays that have an extra , at the end. Eg `var foo = [bar,baz,];` whereas FF doesn't complain.

Comment: @Blair: that's not really appropriate with this error message (it's not a syntax error, it's an object's property/method access error).  @Daniel: post the code in that file...

Comment: @ircmaxell - True. Perhaps it's a use of indexOf then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after typing in the url in that screen-shot ([URL](http://pswb.co.uk/?i=54229abfcfa5649e7003b83dd4755294) ), I was able to find the offending code.  Line 112 of that file (as indicated by the error) is:

```
$('#regGenderM').remoteAttr('checked','checked');
```

Now, it's easy to see the error here.  It should be `removeAttr` instead of `remoteAttr`...

Make that change, and you should be golden.